# Adobe Flex Mobile 4.6 DateSpinner month names

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, adobe

As the topic says I use Adobe Flex Mobile 4.6. Now I am using a Spark component DateSpinner and I want to set month names in other languages, not english. Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple solution, you can do so by setting the    "locale" attribute in the CSS to the desired language code, and it would generate the month names of the desired language.

If the desired language code does not exist, you can create one similar to    SDK_directory\frameworks\projects\framework\bundles\en_US\SharedResources.properties, that's where the month names are defined.